# How to solve this Ricatti-like ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, problem-solving

I have been trying to solve the following ODE

\begin{equation*}
 \dfrac{d\pi}{dx}x=c_1+\pi(x) c_2 + \pi(x)^2(c_3-x),
\end{equation*}
where, for every $i=1,2,3$, $c_i$ is a constant real value.

Separation of variables does not seem to work here, because of the term $\pi^2(x)(c_3-x)$. This equation looks like a Ricatti Equation for which a particular coordinate change could lead to a linear ODE. Does someone knows how to find it?

Best,